# How to get a GitHub repository's commits along with the files that were changed and the changes themselves using GraphQL

Tags: graphql, github-graphql

I am able to get the list of *commits* (with fields like *commit messages*, *oid*, *commit url* etc) along with the number of `changedFiles`, made in a repository on the `master` branch.
However I am not able to figure out how to get **any information about the changes themselves and the files that were changed.**

In v3 of the REST API, the information about the changes were contained in `files`->`patch`, and `files` -> `raw_url` or `blob_url` gave info about the original file itself at that stage.

Q) In v4 of GitHub's API using GraphQL how do I get the corresponding information?

Query I am stuck with right now (showing only 1 commit for brevity)-

```
query {
  rateLimit{
    cost
    remaining
  }
  repository(owner: "elastic", name: "elasticsearch") {
    name
    defaultBranchRef {
      name
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first:1){
            nodes{
              message
              changedFiles
              id
              oid
              treeUrl
              url
              tree{
                oid
              }
            }
            pageInfo{
              hasNextPage
              startCursor
              endCursor
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "rateLimit": {
      "cost": 1,
      "remaining": 4999
    },
    "repository": {
      "name": "elasticsearch",
      "defaultBranchRef": {
        "name": "master",
        "target": {
          "history": {
            "nodes": [
              {
                "message": "Small corrections to HLRC doc for _termvectors (#35221)\n\nRelates to #33447",
                "changedFiles": 2,
                "id": "MDY6Q29tbWl0NTA3Nzc1OmEyYzIyYWQ3YWViMGY4ZDUxNDg2NzdkZDcyMjJhZDQzYWZlZTlhMTc=",
                "oid": "a2c22ad7aeb0f8d5148677dd7222ad43afee9a17",
                "treeUrl": "https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/a2c22ad7aeb0f8d5148677dd7222ad43afee9a17",
                "url": "https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/a2c22ad7aeb0f8d5148677dd7222ad43afee9a17",
                "tree": {
                  "oid": "4f5f11e0e55aeafc4677800959232726a2cd787c"
                }
              }
            ],
            "pageInfo": {
              "hasNextPage": true,
              "startCursor": "a2c22ad7aeb0f8d5148677dd7222ad43afee9a17 0",
              "endCursor": "a2c22ad7aeb0f8d5148677dd7222ad43afee9a17 0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, OP posted this same question on the GitHub community forum in Nov 2018 and the rep said it was not possible as of that time: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/Get-a-repository-s-commits-along-with-changed-patches-and-the/td-p/14436

Comment: Plus, git itself is explicitly excluded, so I took git out of the tags.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious but if the GIthub API cannot give you the diffs, why not just build your own server that maintains its own copy of the repo?
I just realised how old this question is. I hope there's no law against necromancy in these lands.