# Get commit changed files & patch using github API v4 graphQL

Tags: graphql, github-api

In the Rest v3, I could easily query a commit and get the changed files and patch for each file: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit

I don't seem to be able to retrieve this info using the new v4 graphQL, does anyone have a clue how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, it seems that the functionality you are looking for, and much needed in my opinion, isn't supported with GitHub's GraphQL API v4 and it's probably best to stick with the current REST API.

You can refer to the following posts on the official GitHub API support forum and the answers given there by GitHub's staff.

[ref1](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/GraphQL-API-get-list-of-files-related-to-commit/m-p/24666) - 29/5/19

[ref2](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24496) - 5/11/18

Also, a similar question was posted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153142/how-to-get-a-github-repositorys-commits-along-with-the-files-that-were-changed)

Comment: The 2 reference links are broken